# Asp.Net Core 3.0 trouble with Api Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I configure AutoFac for Asp.Net Core 3.0 but now i have trouble with ControllerTestBase class. I know I shouldn't use WebHostBuilder and write other code but I tried many times. I only got new errors.

ControllerTestBase.cs

```
namespace Passenger.Tests.EndToEnd.Controllers
{
    public abstract class ControllerTestsBase
    {
        protected readonly TestServer Server;
        protected readonly HttpClient Client;

        protected ControllerTestsBase()
        {
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
              .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
              {
                // Add TestServer
                webHost.UseTestServer();
                webHost.UseStartup<Startup>();
              });

            var host = hostBuilder.Start();
            Client = host.GetTestClient();

        }

        protected static StringContent GetPayload(object data)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            //Content-Type: "application/json"
            return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }


    }
}
```

AccountControllerTest.cs

```
namespace Passenger.Tests.EndToEnd.Controllers
{
    public class AccountControllerTests : ControllerTestsBase
    {

        [Fact]
        public async Task given_valid_current_and_new_password_it_should_be_changed()
        {
            // Act

            var command = new ChangeUserPassword
            {
                CurrentPassword = "secret",
                NewPassword = "secret2"
            };
            var payload = GetPayload(command);
            var response = await Client.PutAsync("account/password", payload);
            response.StatusCode.Should().BeEquivalentTo(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        } 
    }
}
```

Error Message: https://pastebin.com/9jMdJkXC

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Comment: @MattU look below what errors I have.

Comment: Hi Kondrad,  welcome to StackOverflow. As Matt mentioned, it is important to include any errors (with their stacktrace) in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to use Autofac as .net core 3.0 provides built-in dependency injection.

Read more about [Dependency Injection in Asp.net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Refactor your code and use dependency injection for object initialization.

```
    namespace Passenger.Tests.EndToEnd.Controllers
  {
     public class ControllerTestsBase
    {
    private readonly ITestServer _testServer;
    private readonly HttpClient Client;

    protected ControllerTestsBase(ITestServer testServer,HttpClient client)
    {
        _testServer = testServer;
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.stackoverflow.com");

         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept","application/vnd.github.v3+json");

         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent","HttpClientFactory-Sample");

         Client = client;
    }

    protected static StringContent GetPayload(object data)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        //Content-Type: "application/json"
        return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I need use Autofac for included purposes in the course.